# How I can get localstorage data inside getServerSideProps

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am using NextJS 12. I am trying to get local storage object. When I use localstorage inside `getServerSideProps` I get an error like this `ReferenceError: localStorage is not defined`. I tried to use it outside the function as well but I still get this error. Is there any way to use it inside `getServerSideProps`.

```js
export async function getServerSideProps({ query }) {
    const id = query.id;
    const getData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("form"));
    console.log(getData)
  
    return {
      props: {},
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow, as it refers in the [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-server-side-props)

> If you export a function called `getServerSideProps`  **(Server-Side Rendering)** from a page, Next.js will pre-render this page on each request using the data returned by getServerSideProps.

Localstorage is only available on the **client side** and you are trying to access it in a server side only function , you can use something like

```
if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
// your code 
  const id = query.id;
    const getData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("form"));
    console.log(getData)
  
}
```

Please review [this article](https://flaviocopes.com/nextjs-server-client-code/) to get more information on running client side only code.

Another approach would be to use a [dynamic import](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import#with-no-ssr) where the hello3 component would contain the code accessing local storage.

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'

const DynamicComponentWithNoSSR = dynamic(
  () => import('../components/hello3'),
  { ssr: false }
)

function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      <DynamicComponentWithNoSSR />
      <p>HOME PAGE is here!</p>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Home
```

Answer (score 5):

Another way would be using cookies instead of using `localstorage`, I had the same problem when I developed my last application and I solved it using the `nookies` package

[Nookies: A collection of cookie helpers for Next.js](https://github.com/maticzav/nookies)

Comment: Nice recommendation..

Comment: @JhonnyJr. Cookie is not a replacement for storage.